# Firefox Refuses to Honor Dark Mode

Tags: css, firefox, darkmode

I've tested Firefox 67-83 and absolutely no version actually supports dark mode!

- No, I'm asking a *developer question*.
- No, I'm explicitly not talking about extensions.
- No, I have zero extensions installed.
- Yes, dark mode works perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari changing the *operating system preference only*.
- Yes, I've got Windows 10 and Firefox *both* set to dark mode.
- `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches` returns `false`.
- `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')` shows `media: "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"`.
- Yes, I've created a clean profile.
- Yes, I've tried `about:config` creating and setting `browser.in-content.dark-mode` to `true` in both 67 and 83.

The relevant CSS for *all browsers*:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
{
  :root
 {
  --color_anchor_text: #bfc7d2 !important;
  --color_anchor_focus_text: #8b98ac !important;
  --color_anchor_visited_text: #f2ddca !important;
  --color_body_background: #000 !important;
  --color_form_background:  #222 !important;
  --color_form_background_focus: #444 !important;
  --color_form_text: #fff !important;
  --color_form_text_placeholder: #777 !important;
  --color_primary_background: rgba(34,34,34,.9) !important;
  --color_primary_text: #fff !important;
  --color_status_good: #0c0 !important;
  --color_status_neutral: #aaa !important;
  --color_status_fair: #9c0 !important;
 }
}
```

How do I force Firefox to support dark mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working setting `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme: 1` in the `about:config`
as described here https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/9299

Comment: Great, thank you! I tested and this works in Firefox 71+. It does not work in Firefox 67, 68, 69 or 70 however which are *supposed* to support dark mode. Damn well good enough though!

Comment: In FF 94, this does the same as changing the OS setting. Websites are still using the 'light' color-scheme.